# LUA get date time in format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS

Tags: lua

I was wondering how to go around getting a date string in the following format:

```
date = os.date() -- 11/29/18 09:14:04
```

Into the format of YYYYMMDDHHMMSS, so in this example, I would want to return

```
20181129091404
```

Comment: `os.date("*t")` returns Lua table with fields `year`, `month` and so on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`os.date` accepts format strings. Try `os.date("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")`.

Answer (score 0):

Code to return a string in this value:

```
function generateDateTime()
 local dateTimeTable = os.date('*t')
 local dateTime = dateTimeTable.year .. addZeroForLessThan10(dateTimeTable.month) .. 
 addZeroForLessThan10(dateTimeTable.day) .. addZeroForLessThan10(dateTimeTable.hour) .. addZeroForLessThan10(dateTimeTable.min) .. ddZeroForLessThan10(dateTimeTable.sec)
 return dateTime
end

function addZeroForLessThan10(number)
  if(number < 10) then
    return 0 .. number
  else
    return number
 end
end
```

Comment: Jan 1st 2019 00:00:00 will be `201911000`.  That's not what OP wants :-)